# How to use Visual Studio FileCodeModel without the Addin infrastructure?

Tags: c#, vs-extensibility, c#-code-model

All examples on Visual Studio Extensibility have a `DTE2` object passed in, like so:

```
public void OnConnection(object application, ...)
{
    _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
    ...
}
```

Is it not possible to access a `FileCodeModel` object without a `DTE2` object passed in via an Addin?  I would like to write a standalone C# console application (without using the VS Addin infrastructure) which reads a .cs file and parses it using the `FileCodeModel` class.

```
FileCodeModel fileCM = dte.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel;
```

Of course, in order for the above to work, the `dte` object must be available.  Instead, isn't there an approach like the following *fictional* one which does not rely on a `DTE2` object?

```
FileCodeModel fileCM = new FileCodeModel.ReadCsFile(filepathname);
```

(PS: I know things have changed in Visual Studio 2013, but I am still using Visual Studio 2010.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a DTE instance to use the code model, but you can get a DTE instance outside VS:

HOWTO: Automating Visual Studio .NET from outside the IDE.
http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/

You can also use .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn") without Visual Studio:

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/documentation/compiler/

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/compiler/

http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/videos/compiler/